# Блокировки в куче и в таблице с кластерным индексов отличаются?

Tags: sql-server

Провел эксперимент, вставил 10 записей, а потом следом ставил еще одну, но с открытой тразакцией.

Так вот, при работе с таблицей, где есть кластерный индекс, у меня получается осуществить выборку с использованием условие, которое не охватывает эту не подтвержденную запись, а во втором случае выборка ждет пока завершится транзакция.

Я правильно понимаю, что это происходит из-за того, что приходится просматривать всю кучу в любом случае и так или иначе считать новую запись в то время, как выборка по индексу позволяет это обойти или есть какая-то более научная причина?

Comment: я ваши вопросы уже по заголовкам в списке узнаю до того как смотрю на автора :D

Comment: @teran что поделать. Хоть я и сижу долго на MS SQL, но копать в глубь пришлось только сейчас=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на MSDN:

> Если таблица является кучей и не имеет кластеризованных индексов,
>   требуется просмотреть всю таблицу (выполнить просмотр таблицы), чтобы
>   найти любую строку.

=> в этом скорее всего и дело.

Comment: В общем-то да, + хотел бы доавить что когда вы создаете кластерый индекс на таблице вы меняете порядок доступа к данным, впредь они будут читаться из индекса, это можно проверить так: создать индекс, задизейблить его и сделать селект - будет ошибка.